# Using MrVector with Butter Knife

Tags: android, butterknife

The app I'm working uses vector images, and I'm trying to implement pre-API 21 support for them using MrVector. I'm aware that variables can't be passed into @InjectView() - is there any way of working around this?

Comment: variables? what variables?

Comment: Drawable would be a variable, and I can't pass that into @InjectView().

Comment: i don't get it: MrVector creates Drawables, not Views

Comment: OK, forget it. I'll try to find some other way of doing this.

Comment: I think you either need some kind of fancy custom view that can take a "drawable" index or raw res index as an attribute and initializes that based on API level, or just use normal `@InjectView` and initialize by hand, I guess. Haven't used MrVector so these are wild guesses.